# Why does PIP_ADAPTER_INFO->LeaseExpires contain a different value after each call to GetAdaptersInfo

Tags: c++, windows, network-programming, ipconfig

I am trying to create a program that achieves the same functionality as running the command ipconfg /all in Windows.  I have managed to implement pretty much all the functionality however I am having difficulty getting the correct date and time for when the lease will expire.  I am attempting to get this information by calling GetAdapterInfo and getting the value of LeaseExpires from the PIP_ADAPTER_INFO object that is returned.  However not only does the value for lease expires not match that shown by ipconfig /all but it also changes on every run of the program.  Can anyone spot why this would be happening?

```
#include <WinSock2.h>
#include <iphlpapi.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "Iphlpapi.lib")

PIP_ADAPTER_INFO getAdaptersInfo();
void outputFormatedTime(time_t * ttp);

int main()
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO pai = getAdaptersInfo();

    if (pai)
    {
        for (; pai != NULL; pai = pai->Next)
        {
            if (pai->DhcpEnabled && pai->LeaseObtained)
            {
                printf("Lease Obtained: %llu - ", pai->LeaseObtained);
                outputFormatedTime(&pai->LeaseObtained);
                printf("Lease Expires: %llu - ", pai->LeaseExpires);
                outputFormatedTime(&pai->LeaseExpires);
            }
        }
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, pai);
        pai = NULL;
    }

    return 0;
}

PIP_ADAPTER_INFO getAdaptersInfo()
{
    PIP_ADAPTER_INFO paiResult;
    ULONG ulOutputBufferLength = sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO);

    paiResult = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, sizeof(IP_ADAPTER_INFO));
    if (paiResult == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersInfo\n");
        return paiResult;
    }

    if (GetAdaptersInfo(paiResult, &ulOutputBufferLength) == ERROR_BUFFER_OVERFLOW)
    {
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, paiResult);
        paiResult = (IP_ADAPTER_INFO *)HeapAlloc(GetProcessHeap(), 0, ulOutputBufferLength);
        if (paiResult == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error allocating memory needed to call GetAdaptersInfo\n");
            return paiResult;
        }
    }

    if (!GetAdaptersInfo(paiResult, &ulOutputBufferLength) == NO_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Error calling GetAdaptersInfo\n");
        HeapFree(GetProcessHeap(), 0, paiResult);
        paiResult = NULL;
        return paiResult;
    }

    return paiResult;
}

void outputFormatedTime(time_t * ttp)
{
    struct tm newtime;
    char buffer[32];
    errno_t error;

    error = _localtime32_s(&newtime, (__time32_t *)ttp);
    if (error)
    {
        printf("Invalid Argument to _localtime32_s\n");
    }
    else
    {
        error = asctime_s(buffer, 32, &newtime);
        if (error)
        {
            printf("Invalid Argument to asctime_s\n");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%s", buffer);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unable to duplicate the problem. Both the "Lease obtained" and "Lease Expired" times I get seem correct, and multiple runs produce identical results.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks very much for the feedback, that is interesting.  I will try running it on different systems.  May I ask what OS you tried it on?

Comment: Windows 7 Ultimate.

Comment: Thanks, 64 or 32 bit?

Comment: 64. It's been over a decade since I ran a 32-bit OS (ignoring details like my phone, anyway).

Comment: @JerryCoffin :) the same.  Thanks very much for the information.  It is greatly appreciated.